# How to make an ASMX web service run in singleton mode?

Tags: asp.net, asmx

i am using web service asmx, whenever a new request comes, all objects will be null,
i want to keep some objects after each request, so how to do it?

Comment: could you save the state in some kind of data store? like a database?

Comment: in fact, i want to store my data in objects, i am working on distributed file system, so i need to store requests and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with ASMX web services. You would need to use WCF.

You should be using WCF in any case, as ASMX is a legacy technology.